# Moving two characters simultaneously on a grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble while programming two characters to move simultaneously on a grid. I think I've located the problem, but I'm having trouble implementing a solution.

I've got two characters here that I want to move simultaneously.

[Two characters I want to move at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsVxy.png)

I have a little script checking if there's something in the square that I'm trying to move into on the grid, or if there's an enemy or other player character there to prevent them from overlapping.

You'll see it kinda works when I press 'up' and they both move up at the same time

[both move simultaneously and smoothly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr9x9.png)

Yet when I press 'down' the uppermost character (correctly) detects and prevents collision while the second character moves freely down leaving that space very much inhabitable

[annoying code working the way I wrote it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtCPe.png)

I know that the problem has to do with the order of operations, as the uppermost and leftmost characters are being processed before the others, which is why it works going up or left. I tried writing using a variable to check if the character in collision is about to move, but it caused the characters to overlap and inhabit the same square.

I haven't found any help online, as it seems to be a niche problem, but I know it's been tackled before somewhere.

Honestly any input would be appreciated, I'm fairly new at this and VERY stuck on this problem.

Comment: I believe you have to split your algorithm in 2 parts (phases). In the first phase you move all the characters (storing their original positions somewhere) and in the second phase you check for collisions and, if there's one, restore one of the characters to their original position.

Comment: I did it! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how exactly you store the positions of the characters here's how I would tackle it:

1. Move all characters to their new position without checking if they will overlap with a player and store their positions in a temporary variable.
2. Check for all moved characters if they overlap with something
3. Revert all or all except one movements that cause overlapping
4. Commit all movements

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried to implement this idea, but I've run into the problem where each character is it's own instance of my script moving separately. I think maybe I'll have to rework a script that does movement for all units at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, this solution would require to have something that is managing the characters.
You could get away without that if you have a shared object or variable that contains the grid.
The comment above is correct about splitting the algorithm in 2 phases. In the first one each character instance moves to the desired field and in the second phase they revert the move if there is a collision (they can check that in the shared object). If you want to at least have one character move then the character with the smallest hashcode or id could be allowed to stay.

Comment: I did it! thanks to Pedro and Krakong alike for the help!! I ended up rewriting the movement system from the object itself into one object managing them all, and wrote a recurring check to see if the overlap was resolved. I got roadblocked for a few hours getting stuck in a while loop whenever I tried to resolve three or more characters at once, but I'm here! Thanks again for your help!